# If $f(x) = x$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, is $f$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f$ be defined as:
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
>   x & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q}; \\\\
>   0 & \text{ if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}. \end{cases}  
> $$
>   Is $f$ Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$? Prove it.

We know that the upper sum $U = x$ and lower sum $L=0$.

Since $\lim U\neq \lim L$, $f(x)$ is not Riemann integrable.

Is this sufficient for the proof?

Comment: What does it mean that the upper sum is $x?$ Which is the partition?

Answer (score 0):

Start from the basic. Divide the interval [0,1] into $n$ sub-intervals, each of length $\frac{1}{n}$, i.e. $[0,\frac{1}{n}], [\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}], \cdots, [\frac{n-1}{n}, 1]$, Note that, at each sub-interval of the form $[\frac{i}{n}, \frac{i+1}{n}]$, maximum value of the function = $\frac{i+1}{n}$ and minimum value is 0, as each sub-interval has at-least one rational and one irrational number. Then show that Lower integral converges to 0, but upper integral does not which will show that the function is not Riemann Integrable.